# What is $\mu$-approximablity in Loeb measure (conflicting statements in books)?

Tags: measure-theory, nonstandard-analysis

In Loeb measure, a set is Loeb measurable iff it is $\mu$-approximable, where $\mu$ (roughly speaking) is a finitely additive hypervalued measure over internal sets.

But I found the definitions of $\mu$-approximablity differ in different places.

One is that a set $C$ is $\mu$-approximable if for every hyperreal $\epsilon$, there are internal sets $A,B$ such that  $A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ and $\mu(B-A)<\epsilon$.

Another is roughly the same but instead of every hyperreal $\epsilon$, it says ``for every real $\epsilon$."

Thanks a lot! I am not a math major or anything close, so it's my only place to ask!

References:

1. Goldblatt, Robert. Lectures on the Hyperreals: An introduction to Nonstandard Analysis.
2. Cutland, Nigel. Loeb Measure in Practice.

Comment: It reads to me like "for every hyperreal" should be "for some infinitesimal hyperreal".